# How to protect Ultrasonic Distance Sensor and Circuits from Water Vapours / Weather Conditions?

Tags: arduino, sensor, waterproof

I am making the automatic water controller using Arduino and Ultrasonic Distance Sensors. My prototype is almost ready. But I have a doubt that if I put the sensors on lid of the water tanks, water vapours might cause some problem or could damage the sensor after a few months. Or if by some way water touches the lid it might also damage it. So how to prevent it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple, by using sealed ultrasonic sensors.

Comment: I have unsealed sensors, so how to cover it, using which material?

Comment: @VivekMuthal what does the data sheet say about covering the sensor with materials that don't impede ultrasound. If nothing then contact the manufacturer or do experiments with (say) PTFE.

Comment: Really.  Get rid of the sensors you have, and get sealed ceramic ones.  There is no Ultrasonic transparent 'coating' or 'cover' that I can think of to work with whatever you have.